# Facebook is not returning me the parameters what I ask

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Hi there I'm dealing with a big issue at least for me, I have implemented an older version of Facebook SDK I have many features in my app using this SDK and updated to the most recent version will take a few days, and I don't have time now to do that so what I want to do is simple, I just want to receive the parameters email, last_name and name but Facebook just returns me the name and the id, so could yo have any idea or I am doing something wrong?. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)requestUserInfo{
    // We will request the user's public picture and the user's birthday
    // These are the permissions we need:
    NSArray *permissionsNeeded = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    // Request the permissions the user currently has
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
    {
        // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"]
                                           allowLoginUI:NO
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,     FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", session.accessTokenData.accessToken);
         }];
    }

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                 parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,email,name,last_name" forKey:@"fields"]
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if (!error){

                                  // Parse the list of existing permissions and extract them for easier use
                                  NSMutableArray *currentPermissions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                  NSArray *returnedPermissions = (NSArray *)[result data];
                                  for (NSDictionary *perm in returnedPermissions) {
                                      if ([[perm objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"granted"]) {
                                          [currentPermissions addObject:[perm objectForKey:@"permission"]];
                                      }
                                  }

                                  //NSLog(@"Needed: %@", permissionsNeeded);
                                  //NSLog(@"Current: %@", currentPermissions);

                                  NSMutableArray *requestPermissions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:permissionsNeeded copyItems:YES];
                                  [requestPermissions removeObjectsInArray:currentPermissions];

                                  //NSLog(@"Asking: %@", requestPermissions);

                                  // If we have permissions to request
                                  if ([requestPermissions count] > 0){
                                      // Ask for the missing permissions
                                      [FBSession.activeSession
                                       requestNewReadPermissions:requestPermissions
                                       completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                           if (!error) {
                                               // Permission granted, we can request the user information
                                               [self makeRequestForUserData];
                                           } else {
                                               // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                               // Check out our error handling guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                                               NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);
                                           }
                                       }];
                                  } else {
                                      // Permissions are present
                                      // We can request the user information
                                      [self makeRequestForUserData];

                                  }

                              } else {
                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                  // Check out our error handling guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                                  NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);
                              }
                          }];



}
```

And this is the info:

```
 llega el objeto:{
    id = 10210924411602727;
    name = "Del Mar Sal";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below i attached the FB Login & Fetch details from Facebook. Try it that code & Compare.

```
- (IBAction)facebook_BtnTap:(id)sender {


    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];


  [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"]handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {

         if (error) {

             NSLog(@"Process error");



         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");

         } else {

             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                 // Do work
                 [self GetUserDetails];

             }
         }
     }];
}


-(void)GetUserDetails
{
    BOOL LOGGING;

    if (LOGGING) {
        return;
    }
    LOGGING = YES;
    //    [super startLoader];

    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@“Check Already login");
        //[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI: YES];

        // [self back:nil];

        // return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setValue:@"id,name,email,first_name,last_name,birthday,picture.type(large),location,hometown,gender" forKey:@"fields"];


    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {


             NSString* email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
             NSString* fname = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
             NSString* lname = [result objectForKey:@"last_name"];

             NSString* userName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
             NSString* gender = [result objectForKey:@"gender"];

             NSDictionary* hometown=[result objectForKey:@"hometown"];
             NSString* country = [hometown objectForKey:@"name"];

             NSString* birthday=[result objectForKey:@"birthday"];

             //   NSArray* photo =[[result objectForKey:@"picture"]valueForKey:@"data"];
             //       NSDictionary* location = [result objectForKey:@"location"];

             //   NSString* city = [location valueForKey:@"name"];

             //    NSString*  fbPhoto = [photo valueForKey:@"url"];


             NSString*   fid = [result objectForKey:@"id"];


     }];

}
```